# php array_slice modifies the global variable which was assigned by value to the variable in the array_slice call. why?

Tags: php

Considering the code below:

```
// build post global
global $post;
$post = (object) array(
    'posts' => array_map(function($thingy){
        return (object) array('name' => $thingy);
    }, array('thingy1', 'thingy2', 'thingy3', 'thingy4', 'thingy5', 'thingy6', 'thingy7', 'thingy8')),
);

// assign post global to new variable
$index_post = $post;

error_log(var_export('post posts before slice', true));
error_log(var_export(count($post->posts), true));

// assign to new variable again
$index_post_posts = $index_post->posts;
// slice & reassign
$index_post->posts = array_slice($index_post_posts, 5, 2);

error_log(var_export('post posts after slice', true));
error_log(var_export(count($post->posts), true));
```

Output:

```
'post posts before slice'
8
'post posts after slice'
2
```

Expected output:

```
'post posts before slice'
8
'post posts after slice'
8
```

Why is the value of $post->posts changing when $index_post_posts has array_slice called on it? Are globals always assigned by reference in php or something? How does one get around this limitation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Objects are always passed by reference in PHP... use the `clone` keyword to bypass this.